# How to get variables from other database nodes with Cloud Function .onWrite (Firebase)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set some variables to send to pass into a function if a Firebase node is set to true.  I am trying to use the `.parent` and `.val()` function to set a `customer_id`, based on the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

```
exports.newCloudFunction = functions.database.ref('/user/{userId}/sources/saveSource').onWrite(event => {
// Retrieve true/false value to verify whether card should be kept on file
const saveSource = event.data.val();

if (saveSource) {
  let snap = event.data;
  let customer_id = snap.ref.parent.child('customer_id').val();
  console.log(customer_id);
  // pass customer_id into function
}
```

I was expecting `snap.ref.parent` to reference `/sources` and `.child('customer_id').val()` to access the value from the `customer_id` key.

However, when I try to run this function I get the following error:

```
TypeError: snap.ref.parent.child(...).val is not a function
at exports.linkCardToSquareAccount.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:79:56)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:35:20
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
```

How can I reference a node outside the scope of the original onWrite location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just call `.val()` on a database reference and expect to get the data at that location. You need to add a value listener in order to get new data.

Fortunately, this is fully supported inside of Cloud Functions:

```
exports.newCloudFunction = functions.database.ref('/user/{userId}/sources/saveSource').onWrite(event => {
    // Retrieve true/false value to verify whether card should be kept on file
    const saveSource = event.data.val();

    if (saveSource) {
        const customerIdRef = event.data.adminRef.parent.child('customer_id')
        // attach a 'once' value listener to get the data at this location only once
        // this returns a promise, so we know the function won't terminate before we have retrieved the customer_id
        return customerIdRef.once('value').then(snap => {
            const customer_id = snap.val();
            console.log(customer_id);
            // use customer_id here
        });
    } 
});
```

You can learn more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you Bradley!!

Comment: Link deprecated. Refer to this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions